# How are dividends determined?

Tags: railroad-tycoon, railroad-tycoon-deluxe

When the railroad is producing large profits, dividends are automatically declared and paid to shareholders. How large do profits have to be before dividends are paid? What determines the amount of dividends paid? Is it possible to adjust the amount (e.g. zero dividends or extraordinary large dividends)?

Comment: Which version are we talking about here? The original railroad tycoon? Railroad Tycoon 2? Railroad Tycoon 3?

Comment: @StampedeXV The question is tagged [tag:railroad-tycoon-deluxe].

Comment: ok, sorry. I don't even remember a stock market in original RT - could only speculate according to my observation of RT 2